# How to generate download .pdf for Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, download, ms-word

I'm working on a website in which a user enters a name and then presses a button that prompts the server to create a pdf file according to the information provided, and then sends the file to the user.

I'm testing the website on my laptop without IIS.

I needed the pdf to be hebrew and couldn't find a pdfwrite with vb on hebrew; instead, I create a MS Word document and then convert it to pdf using the code below.

This  works fine on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but on Internet Explorer the page disconnects before the download.  It disconnects when the create word statement is executed.

Can anyone help me?

```
      Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles      Button1.Click
      Dim strname As String
      strname = TextBox1.Text.Trim

      Dim oword As New word.Application
      Dim odoc As New word.Document
      oword = CreateObject("word.Application")

      odoc = oword.Documents.Add("C:\documents\tamp.dotx")

      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name1").Range.Text = strname
      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name2").Range.Text = strname
      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name3").Range.Text = strname
      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name4").Range.Text = strname
      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name5").Range.Text = strname
      odoc.Bookmarks.Item("name6").Range.Text = strname

      odoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(Server.MapPath("\neshume.pdf"), 17)
      Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("\neshume.pdf"))
      end sub
```

Comment: What does Event Log say?

Comment: My guess is that it is failing on the next line where you create a file.Obviously the security levels in the IE browser is different from the others and is not allowing access to the path C:\documents\tamp.dotx

Comment: Chiwda so what can i do to correct this?

Comment: I think that page headers are not set correctly to be accepted by IE. Would you try to narrow the problem removing all code except 
Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("\neshume.pdf"))? Would you try to download the .pdf only (address should be something as http: //localhost:port/neshume.pdf)? I recommend using @name to address a comment response to appropriate person.

Comment: @IvanH i tried with out any other code and it failed

Answer (score 1):

turns out the problem was not in the code something was wrong with my machine i tested it on a different computer and it worked perfectly

Comment: Even though the problem did come from your code, it might help others with similar issues if you explained what was wrong with your machine that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("\neshume.pdf"))
```

with

```
 Response.Redirect("neshume.pdf")
```

You can't redirect to full path (Maybe it was accepted by ff because it is running on the same computer).

Comment: it does not seem that this is the problem the website crashes when it process the code  oword = CreateObject("word.Application")

Comment: It crashes on CreateObject in ff and not in ie? It is strange. Would you publish exact message? Do you tried to put the breakpoint to the place?

Comment: it closes in ie and not firefox i tried the breakpoint at each point and it happens at the above statemet

Comment: Would you make your code as simple as possible (document, no parameters fixed path)? I try to copy/paste it and we'll see.